# Quarkus OpenId Connect Bearer Token Integration/Security Testing

Tags: quarkus

I'm following https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect#integration-testing-wiremock to create some tests for my Quarkus app:

```
@QuarkusTest
@TestHTTPEndpoint(BannerApi.class)
@QuarkusTestResource(OidcWiremockTestResource.class)
public class BannerApiTest {
    @Test
    public void testListUnauthenticated() {
        when().get().then().statusCode(401);
    }
}
```

I followed the setup as-is, except I created `application.properties` in `src/test/resources` with the following contents:

```
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=${keycloak.url}/realms/quarkus/
quarkus.oidc.client-id=quarkus-service-app
quarkus.oidc.application-type=service
smallrye.jwt.sign.key.location=privateKey.jwk
```

But here's what I get:

```
2021-08-03 21:18:41,731 INFO  [org.ecl.jet.uti.log] (pool-5-thread-1) Logging initialized @14312ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
...
2021-08-03 21:18:42,041 INFO  [io.qua.tes.oid.ser.OidcWiremockTestResource] (pool-5-thread-1) Keycloak started in mock mode: http://localhost:64289
...
2021-08-03 21:18:44,348 INFO  [org.ecl.jet.ser.han.ContextHandler] (main) Stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@520fdce4{/__admin,null,STOPPED}
2021-08-03 21:18:44,349 INFO  [io.qua.tes.oid.ser.OidcWiremockTestResource] (main) Keycloak was shut down

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus

    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.throwBootFailureException(QuarkusTestExtension.java:686)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestClassConstructor(QuarkusTestExtension.java:759)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(ApplicationImpl.zig:1114)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Configuration validation failed:
    keycloak.url does not map to any root
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ConfigRecorder.registerConfigMappings(ConfigRecorder.java:67)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ConfigBuildStep$registerConfigClasses-2116437784.deploy_0(ConfigBuildStep$registerConfigClasses-2116437784.zig:292)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ConfigBuildStep$registerConfigClasses-2116437784.deploy(ConfigBuildStep$registerConfigClasses-2116437784.zig:40)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: io.smallrye.config.ConfigValidationException: Configuration validation failed:
    keycloak.url does not map to any root
    at io.smallrye.config.ConfigMappingProvider.mapConfiguration(ConfigMappingProvider.java:829)
    at io.smallrye.config.ConfigMappingProvider.mapConfiguration(ConfigMappingProvider.java:785)
    at io.smallrye.config.ConfigMappings.mapConfiguration(ConfigMappings.java:54)
    ... 49 more


org.opentest4j.TestAbortedException: Boot failed


    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.throwBootFailureException(QuarkusTestExtension.java:688)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestClassConstructor(QuarkusTestExtension.java:759)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
...
```

As you can see from the log, `Keycloak started in mock mode: http://localhost:64289 ...` but then `keycloak.url does not map to any root`.

Where do I miss? I'm using Quarkus 2.1.0.

Comment: The actual class seems to be filling the value correctly https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/2.1/test-framework/oidc-server/src/main/java/io/quarkus/test/oidc/server/OidcWiremockTestResource.java. It is possible that you have redefined somewhere the variable keycloak.url or something like that?

Comment: @karelss I think it's a regression in Quarkus 2. I down graded to 1.13.7 and it's working.

Comment: It is possible, have you spoke to the devs over zulip chat ?, It might be worth to open an issue on github. Also they had release the 2.1.1 which contains some fixes maybe its already included